# How to get the next sibling with GPathResult

Tags: xml, groovy, xmlslurper, gpath

How can I get the next sibling of an GPathResult? For example I have the following code:

```
def priorityIssue = xmlReport.'**'.find { Issue ->
   Issue.Priority.text() == priority
}
```

How do I get priorityIssue's next sibling?

Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer solve the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More or less this is the way to go:

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText('''
<issues>
    <issue>
        <id>1</id>
        <priority>1</priority>
    </issue>
    <issue>
        <id>2</id>
        <priority>2</priority>
    </issue>
</issues>
''')
def p = '1' 
def priorityIssue = xml.'**'.find { issue ->
    issue.priority.text() == p
}
def kids = priorityIssue.parent().children().list()
def idx = kids.indexOf(priorityIssue)
def sibling = kids[++idx]
assert sibling.id.text() == '2'
```

Comment: As for Groovy 2.3.6 the `.list()` part is excessive and leads to a runtime error. Alles fine without it.

Comment: @PavelVlasov without the list() the rest of the code doesn't work and that is the answer to get the next sibling.

Answer (score 0):

The solution with `indexOf()` **works only if you search for a node with unique text content**. The problem is, that `NodeChild` instances are always compared by `text()`, see `GPathResult#hashCode()`. I had to get to the actual nodes instead of their proxies `NodeChild`.

```
xml = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText('''\
<issues>
  <issue>
    <first/>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </issue>
  <issue>   
    <second/>
    <priority>2</priority>
  </issue>
  <issue>   
    <third/>
    <priority>1</priority>
  </issue>  
</issues>
''')

third = xml.'**'.find{it.name() == 'third'}
thirdIssue = third.parent()
issues = thirdIssue.parent().children()
println 'wrong: ' + issues.list().indexOf(thirdIssue)
println 'right: ' + issues.findIndexOf{it[0] == thirdIssue[0]}
```

**Extra tip**: You can also use `Integer.toHexString(System.identityHashCode(issue))` to check, what instances are you dealing with.